# Windows 7 "Not genuine" after imaging Z200 computers

Tags: windows-7, images, activation

We created images from Windows 7, loaded on a HP Z200 workstation. We have added all our software we need on this image and then, sysprep'ed it. So now, when I push the image thru Zenworks on my 5 other Z200, I get the error message that my copy is not genuine... Normal since it has been imaged with the first PC's PID and Key.

But now I'm wondering how I can modify the information on the imaged computers. Here is what I've done so far.

- I can't change the information in the System Information page. It's Not available. -- The Software Protection Service is set as Startup (Delayed)
- I successfuly changed the CD Key from the command prompt (slmgr.vbs -ipk (CDKEY)) -- That was when I was not joined on my domain because I got the error message: Need elevated privileges even if I'm domain admin... ¿¿??¿¿
- I can't activate it using slmgr.vbs -ato.

So basicaly I'm trying to find a way to activate Windows 7 Pro on my 5 other Z200 with the CK Key that is attached with the OEM sticker on the computer. Is there any tools that can give me a hand? A registry key that I need to mod/del/add?

Thank you very much in advance!

David.

Comment: The image has been built directly from the already installed windows 7 coming with the Z200. I'm pretty that the thing that mess it up. Right?

Comment: Please write it down as an answer so I'll give your points.

Answer (score 7):

To install Windows this way you need a volume license not individual licences tied to each machine.

By doing it this way you are cloning a specific installation, which is against Microsoft's license terms. There is a utility you could get for XP which allowed you to enter a new Windows key.

The tool is called "KeyUpdateTool.exe" and can be downloaded directly from Microsoft using [this download link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=50346&clcid=0x409). I have no idea whether it works for Windows 7.

Comment: Is that tool legit?

Comment: It's from Microsoft (check the URL or do a search yourself) so yes. However, double check it still works with Windows 7 it's billed as an XP tool.